# mule sftp archive not continuing flow

Tags: activemq-classic, mule

Im having major issues with Mule 3 and files being read and that later should be put on some standard queue on ActiveMQ.

basically its a really simple service, initially started that on inbound starts off by

This file is read correctly from the SFTP area, and in the mule log for the reading application its stated that the file is written to the specified archiveDir..

After this, its silent, nothing else happens... the file is just placed in the archiveDir and neithe ActiveMQ or Mule3 gives any indications to that something have gone wrong...

The queue names etc etc is all correct.

Basically the same environment is running on a second server, with no disturbance..

Is there any commonly known issues that could make mule not continue on with its processing putting the file on queue?

Thx in advance!

Comment: It sound like you have pointed your outbound to that specified archiveDir and mule done it's job. Did this process ever worked? what configurations used to put messages on ActiveMQ queue?

Comment: Also, could you share with us you mule configuration?